# How to set a QVariant structure?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QList` structure containing a `QVariant`:

```
typedef struct EXTRA_PARAMS_DEF {
    QString name;
    QVariant val;
    int channel;
} EXTRA_PARAMS;
QList<EXTRA_PARAMS> EP;
```

Why I cannot set this `QVariant` with this function?

```
int setParam(QVariant value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<EP.count(); i++)
    {
        EP.at(i).val = value;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> error: C2678: '=' binary ': no operator found, accepting a left part
>
> operation of type' const QVariant ' There is no acceptable conversion

How can I do to set this `QVariant`? Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QList<T>::at(int)` returns a `const T &`, which you can't assign to.

Use `QList<T>::operator[]` instead, which returns a `T &`

```
EP[i].val = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign because the return value of `QList::at` is a `const EXTRA_PARAMS`, which propagates constness to the `val` member.

`operator[]` has a non-const overload, so replace `.at(i)` with `[i]`

```
int setParam(QVariant value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<EP.count(); i++)
    {
        EP[i].val = value;
    }
}
```